# Advice on code structure to prevent duplication of code (Python, lists)

Tags: python, list, structure

The scenario at play is that I have an ordered list of items. I want to convert that list into a single string.

However.

It's not simply a matter of converting each item into a string and concatenating. I need to do some processing on the list as part of the conversion.

Here's a rough example:

List:

```
[1, 
 2,
 3,
 0,
 1,
 9,
 -4,
 3,
 2]
```

The output I desire would be this:

```
The total of a group is 6.
The total of a group is 10.
The total of a group is 5.
```

Here's the code I've written that can do this:

```
total = 0
result = ""
for item in myList:
    if (item <= 0):
        result += "The total of a group is %d.\n" % total
        total = 0
        continue
    total += item

# NOTICE THE CODE DUPLICATION HERE...
result += "The total of a group is %d.\n" % total

print result
```

The problem is I have the `result +=` in the code *twice*. The reason for that is that we have no guarantee that the last item in the list is an item that is going to cause the code that actually appends the string to execute. (i.e. we don't have any guarantee that it's a number 0 or less.)

The obvious solution to this might be "check the last item in the list and if it's not <= 0 then add a 0 as the last item." This would work on a list of primitives like this. It however would not work on a list of objects or complex types, or if the comparison is more involved than simply <= 0.

So the question is: IS there a good way to structure this code such so that I am not duplicating code, which of course introduces a huge possibility for errors?

Thanks!

F

Answer (score 7):

If you're allowed to you can use `itertools.groupby` to group positive numbers, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 9, -4, 3, 2]
group_totals = [sum(g) for k, g in groupby(data, lambda L: L > 0) if k]
for group_total in group_totals:
    print 'The sum of a group is', group_total
print 'Total of all groups is', sum(group_totals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **numpy** as:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 9, -4, 3, 2]
>>> a=np.array(a)
>>> total=["The total of a group is "+str(sum(i[i>0])) for i in np.split(a,np.where(a<=0)[0])]
>>> total.append("Total of all groups is "+str(sum(a[a>0])))
>>> for i in total: print i
... 
The total of a group is 6
The total of a group is 10
The total of a group is 5
Total of all groups is 21
```